# How do you get the minimum and maximum memory allocation of a SQL instance using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, memory, sql, sql-server-2008-r2, tsql

I'm managing about 90 SQL Server instances and need a query to determine how much memory has been allocated to each instance. Please note, I'm not asking how to set it, just to see what it's currently set to without using the Management Studio.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When executed this on my system. values is given as 2147483647 , my system RAM is only 2 GB, in this case how I consider return value as MB.
if I conside it as MB then my system RAM should be 2097152 GB

Comment: It is the configured value, not your actual RAM. It allows SQL Server to take up to this amount of memory (including virtual memory)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this on the `master` database:

```
SELECT name, value, value_in_use, [description] 
FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name like '%server memory%'
ORDER BY name OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Gives you `max server memory (MB)` and `min server memory (MB)`

Comment: Just a note if you are using sqlcmd.exe: I'd recommend using the `-W` switch to trim whitespaces as described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1b7b4234-e55c-41b0-9e25-3a61dea3ee2f/sqlcmd-strip-white-space) - there are quite a lot of them (at least on my setup).