# Why do I get different memory numbers using TSQL versus the GUI?

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2014, tsql

I'm preparing to bump up our `max server memory` value after a RAM upgrade on our server. I'm testing the commands out on a test SQL Server and I'm not sure why I'm seeing different results with T-SQL versus the GUI.
I changed the memory on the test server to 24GB as follows:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'max server memory', 24576;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

In the GUI I see 24576.

But using the query below, I see 22421. What did I do wrong?

```
SELECT (physical_memory_in_use_kb/1024) AS Used_Memory_By_SqlServer_MB
FROM sys.dm_os_process_memory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is returning memory used by SQL, not the max server memory it's allowed to consume.

[How do you get the minimum and maximum memory allocation of a SQL instance using T-SQL?](https://serverfault.com/questions/408919/how-do-you-get-the-minimum-and-maximum-memory-allocation-of-a-sql-instance-using)

This will show you how to get that value via query.

```
SELECT name, value, value_in_use, [description] 
FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name like '%server memory%'
ORDER BY name OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```